# Given a matrix of linear transformation, find new bases s.t. the linear transformation is represented as another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation such that $[T] = A$. Find bases $X$ and $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively, such that $[T]^X_C = B$.

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2\\
2 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know if $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ and $C=\{c_1,c_2\}$ then

$$[T]^X_C(x1)=c_1+2c_2 $$

$$[T]^X_C(x2)=3c_1 $$

$$[T]^X_C(x3)=2c_1-c_2$$

But I don't know how to make use of $A$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a linear trasformation is completely determined by the action on its basis elements so you know that you have two basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $ \{w_1,w_2\}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T(e_1) & =  w_1 \\  
T(e_2) & = &w_2 \\ 
T(e_3) &= 2w_1 -&3w_2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and you are looking for basis $\{e_1^*,e_2^*,e_3^*\}$ and $ \{w_1^*,w_2^*\}$
such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T(e_1^*) & = w_1^* +2w_2^*\\  
T(e_2^*) & =  3w_1^*& \\ 
T(e_3^*) &= 2w_1^* -w_2^*
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now take the same basis for $T(V)$ which means that $ \{w_1^*,w_2^*\} = \{w_1,w_2\}$ and try to build basis elements $e_1^*,e_2^*,e_3^*$ with $e_1,e_2,e_3$. You'll see that the choices

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
e_1^*& = e_1+&2e_2\\
e_2^*& = 3e_1\\
e_3^*& = &2e_2+e_3
\end{split}
\end{equation}

work. If you want a particular solution I suggest to use standard basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Oh so the X and C values are not unique? It depends on the {e1,e2,e3} I choose?

Comment: Also how did you get e1* = e1+2e2? Is it from T(e1*) = T(e1+2e2)? But is this assuming T being injective?

Comment: yes they depend on the values of $e_1,e_2,e_3$. No I made the "inverse" process which doesn't require injectivity, you can think of it like this: if $e_1^* = e_1+2e_2$ then $T(e_1^*) = w_1+2w_2$ which is what you wanted, you are choosing them you are not using injectivity

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't e3* = 2e1-e2 also work? But then {e1*, e2*, e3*} is not a basis because they are linearly dependent?

Comment: yes, true...indeed I checked that  $\{e_1^*, e_2^*, e_3^*\} $ was a basis after I wrote it :-)

Comment: ohh i see. Thank u!